# IE gives error: Access is denied when pie.css file is included in css rule behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use pie.htc file to show CSS3 effects on ie-7 and ie-8 browsers. However when I run the file in IE it gives me Access is denied error. The path is correct, when I copy paste the path in browser, it gives me that file. So what's amiss here ? I read in some other question, that pie.htc should be present on same domain. what does that mean. My css file in which I am setting behavior attribute and pie.htc file both are on same domain. what else must be done ?

Comment: what version is the `pie.htc`?

Comment: could you provide a url or a code example that shows the same problem on www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: for e.g I am including a javascript on webpage from domain http://ph.samlpescripts.com/. When the script is loaded, inside it I am assigning styles to an element. If ie is detected, I am adding behavior attribute with as `behavior: url('http://ph.samlpescripts.com/pie/PIE.htc')`. Now what surprises me is that javascript from same domain was loaded, but htc file couldn't

Comment: i am getting the same error but i am not on a webserver, i am currently working with static html files...is a webserver necessary to serve .htc files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is almost always down to the cross domain issue, it is worth noting that the following are not equal and if you are viewing **http://www.example.com/** and the script location is **http://example.com/** you will see the access denied error.

- http://example.com/
- http://www.example.com/
- http://scripts.example.com/

If you are sure this isn't the problem, can you point us to an example page?

Comment: for e.g I am including a javascript on webpage from domain `ph.samlpescripts.com`. When the script is loaded, inside it I am assigning styles to an element. If ie is detected, I am adding behavior attribute with as `behavior: url('http://ph.samlpescripts.com/pie/PIE.htc')`. Now what surprises me is that javascript from same domain was loaded, but htc file couldn't